# Rspec test issue not producing proper response

Tags: rspec, ruby-1.9.3

I receive the following response when I try to run rspec tests.

> > user.respond_to?(:name)
> >
> > ## should get "true" but get the following error instead

```
(added)    **NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object
from (irb):2
from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Instead of receiving a "true" or "false" response. Any ideas?

From Gemfile
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
ruby '1.9.3'

Here is the exact test and erro from Hartl tutorial 6.2.2 Validating Presence

```
user = User.new(name: "", email: "mhartl@example.com")
>> user.save
=> false
```

*false is the response I am supposed to get, the error above is what I receive.

Here is my user.rb file

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessible :name, :email

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Here is my user_spec.rb file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

   before { @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com") }

   subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
end
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the first line of the error message? The one that tells you exactly what went wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I get the part I attached originally in a few different scenarios so I was wondering if I was missing something more general. But I updated above for this case in particular...